# SIM300cz AT command returns -1

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm

I connected SIM300cz module's GSM board with Arduino Mega. The GSM board has the pins VCC, GND, RXD, TXD, GND, RI, DTR, STATUS, PWKEY and GND. I connected the GNDs with Arduino's GND, VCC to Arduinos 5V (took power from Arduino), RXD to pin 5, TXD to pin 6 (because of using software serial) and PWKEY to pin 53. My code is as follows:

```c
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial GPRS(5, 6);

int inputPinTempSensor = 0;
float tempCelsius = 0 ;
float thresholdTemp = 45;

void setup()
{
  GPRS.begin(9600);               // the GPRS baud rate
  Serial.begin(9600);  // the Serial port of Arduino baud rate.
  pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(53, HIGH);
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  GPRS.print("AT+CREG/r");
  Serial.print(GPRS.read());
  delay(2000);
}
```

The AT command response should be something like "ok" but it's returning -1 for every loop waiting 2 seconds. Why and what could be the solution?

**Edit:**

Sorry for the mistakes. I was trying different ways with carriage return and new line characters to make it work. Now the code is:

```c
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial GPRS(5, 6);

void setup()
{
  GPRS.begin(9600);               // the GPRS baud rate
  Serial.begin(9600);  // the Serial port of Arduino baud rate.
  pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(53, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  GPRS.println("AT+CREG");
}

void loop() {
  while(GPRS.available()){
    Serial.print(GPRS.read());
  }
}
```

Now it gives no responses at all. Actually after buying the module I was trying with [these](https://github.com/Arduino-IN/demos/tree/master/GSM%2BArduino/Arduino-Code) examples and they were not working either. So, I thought to test if the AT commands were working properly. I could be a problem with my wiring too.

Comment: Did you wire DTR to GND?

Comment: Yes, I tried with both keeping it opened and by adding to GND.

Comment: BTW, pin 53 is to pull up PWKEY. It's connected to PWKEY.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 mistakes in your code:

First, you should ensure that the 3AT3 commands are termintaed by a new line character:

```
GPRS.print("AT+CREG/r");
```

should be changed into:

```
GPRS.println("AT+CREG/r");
```

or:

```
GPRS.print("AT+CREG/r\n");
```

Nite that I am not sure why you added `/r` at the end of the AT command, is that supposed to be part of the command? If your intention was to force a new line, then you meant `\r` not `/r`, which is not really a new line character but a carriage return (that might be interpreted the same by yur GSM module, but not necessarily).

The the second mistake in your code, is directly calling `GPRS.read()` **without** first waiting for a character to be available; in this situation, `GPRS.read()` will always return `-1` as a specific value meaning "no available character to read".

So you should change your code to something like:

```
// 1st wait for a character to be available
while (!GPRS.available()) {
}
// Then read all available characters and log them to Serial
while (GPRS.available()) {
    Serial.print(GPRS.read());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I edited my question. I still have problems.

Comment: Note that GPRS.read() will return  -1  if the input buffer is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The correct AT command is `AT+CREG?\r`. A delay of at least 500ms is also advised after every command, though a timeout loop would be better. Since you didn't send any other commands, the modem will have no further responses for you and the Arduino will return -1 to any Serial.read()s, indicating there's nothing to be read.